# Swift button target "self" doesn't work inside the ViewController of a ScrollVIew

Tags: button, swift, scrollview

Something rather trivial but I can't find the answer(not on this website or in the Swift books I own).

I have the following construction:
- A ScrollView created inside the main ViewController
- Inside this ScrollView there is another ViewController which houses all the UI elements.
- One of the UI elements is a button with a target assigned to it. Whenever I use this button my application crashes.

The code for the button is fairly trivial:

```
let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
view.addSubview(button)
```

The code to catch the button event:

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    println("Button tapped")
}
```

I suspect that the issue comes from the "self" keyword in the addTarget (when I create the button from my main viewController, it works just fine. Can anyone tell me how I can solve this / the logic behind it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I think I've figured it out.

I think I was a little confused from languages I've used in the past  (like Actionscript).

What I was doing was creating a ViewController with a ScrollView and inside that ScrollView I would add another ViewController with all the elements.

The approach I'm now using is creating the ViewController with the ScrollView and I now directly add all the elements to the ScrollView instead of the extra ViewController.

The button now works so I guess nesting another ViewController inside the ScrollView is simply overkill and adding a layer of complexity (I suppose that the ScrollView component by default extends from UIView so there is no point in having another View).

Thanks all